# Resolving compiler error: pointer potentially uninitialized

Tags: c++, if-statement

I need to resolve an error that the compiler is picking up on - I understand why it's picking up on that error but need to resolve it since the function (throwing the error) will only execute when the pointer *is* initialized.

Here is my pseudo code:

```
if (incoming_message_exists) 
{
    msg_class* current_msg;

    /*current_msg will become either value_1 or value_2*/

    /*code block 1*/
    if (condition_is_fulfilled)
    {
        current_msg = value_1;
    }

    /*code block 2*/
    else 
    {
        current_msg = value_2;
    }

    /*code block 3*/
    /*bool function performed on current_msg that is throwing error*/
    if (function(current_msg))
    {
        //carry out function 
    }
}
```

I would prefer not to perform code block 3 within 1 and 2, but if that's the only solution then I will. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Initalize current_msg with NULL (or null_ptr in c++11)

Comment: What kind of dumb compiler is this? You assign a value to `msg_class` in both branches of the `if` statement... It cannot **possibly** be uninitialized...

Comment: @H2CO3 Unless there is an `else if` block not being showed where it's not set.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Right, but I don't see one anywhere.

Comment: @H2CO3 The `/* code block n */` comments made me think that we're being shown branches from two different `if` statements so the compiler is probably correct that `msg_class` isn't guaranteed to be initialised

Comment: @simonc So basically that `else` is not really an `else`? What kind of dumb programmer is this, then?

Comment: the `else` *is* an `else`! it will be either value_1 OR value_2. the `/*code block x*/` statements are only here so I can refer to them easily with numbers

and it's the vs2012 c++ compiler.

Comment: There is no error here and there is no use of an uninitialized variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are the `if` and `else` branches you show us are from two different `if` statements?

If they are, your current code is capable of leaving `current_msg` uninitialised.  This will likely crash when you reach `function(current_msg)`.

If you've shown us two branches for the same `if` statement, your compiler is wrong - there is no danger of `current_msg` not being initialised.  You may still need to change your code to suppress the warning however, say if you build with warnings as errors.

You can fix/suppress the warning simply by initialising `current_msg` when it is declared

```
msg_class* current_msg = NULL;
```

If you don't have other code in either branch, you could also initialise using the ternary operator

```
msg_class* current_msg = condition_is_fulfilled? value_1 : value_2;
```

If the warning was genuine, you'll also have to either check that `function` copes with being passed a `NULL` argument or guard against this

```
if (current_msg != NULL && function(current_msg))
```

Comment: "Your current code appears capable of leaving current_msg uninitialised" - not quite. It's assigned to in both branches of the `if` statement.

Comment: @H2CO3 As per my comment on the question, I thought the `/*code block 2*/` comment suggested that we were being shown two branches from different `if` statements.  I'll modify my answer to explain this.